# How does the terrain attack bonus promotions work?

Tags: civilization-5

For example, Barrage: +15% strength when attacking enemies in rough terrain like forest and hills.

The question is, does it mean: 1) I'm initiating an attack when standing on a rough terrain or 2) The enemy is standing on a rough terrain when I'm attacking it?

Google-fu doesn't bring up any result other than a comprehensive list of possible promotions, which for some reason lack explanations like the one I'm looking for

Comment: ```````2```````

Comment: Alright, thanks. Please post it as an answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number 2. Terrain promotions are based on where the defender is standing so barrage will give you a bonus attacking into hills/forest.

For melee promotions, this also applies to defending. If a unit with Drill is standing in a forest/hill, it will get a bonus to its combat strength if it is attacked.